# How to add SQL query by variable in DB::Select() in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I have a `DB::select()` query where I want to add dynamic SQL by variable.

This is what I'm trying to do but it returns SQL syntax error.

```
$restaurantSql = "";
$restaurantIds = [6,43,51];

if ($someOtherVariable) {
    $restaurantSql = "AND orders.restaurant_ids IN (".implode(",", $restaurantIds).")";
}

$result = DB::select(
    "SELECT *
    FROM orders
    JOIN restaurants ON orders.restauant_id = restaurants.id
    WHERE orders.status = 'complete' :restaurant_sql AND
    orders.created_at >= :start_date",
    ["restaurant_sql" => $restaurantSql, "start_date" => $startDate]
);
```

The `start_date` works as per the documentation from Laravel but the `restaurant_sql` is not working. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here

```
$result = DB::select(
    "SELECT *
    FROM orders
    JOIN restaurants ON orders.restauant_id = restaurants.id
    WHERE orders.status = 'complete'". $restaurantSql. "AND
    orders.created_at >= :start_date",
    ["restaurant_sql" => $restaurantSql, "start_date" => $startDate]
);
```

Comment: I don't want to add the restaurant ids, I want to add the whole SQL dynamically.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I changed the code. please check it again

Comment: Didn't know it can work like that. Thank you sm